# Ignition Provider for azure ubuntu vm

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, systemd, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to write a `systemd service` file using `ignition provider` of `terraform` like below for `ubuntu OS`

```
# Systemd unit data resource containing the unit definition
data "ignition_systemd_unit" "example" {
  name = "example.service"
  content = "[Service]\nType=oneshot\nExecStart=/usr/bin/echo Hello World\n\n[Install]\nWantedBy=multi-user.target"
}

# Ingnition config include the previous defined systemd unit data resource
data "ignition_config" "example" {
  systemd = [
    data.ignition_systemd_unit.example.rendered,
  ]
}

# Create a CoreOS server using the Igntion config.
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  # ...

  user_data = data.ignition_config.example.rendered
}
```

and in `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine` i gave like below

```
custom_data = data.ignition_config.example.rendered
```

I am getting an error like below

```
Error: expected "custom_data" to be a base64 string, got {"ignition":{"config":{},"timeouts":{},"version":"2.1.0"},"networkd":{},"passwd":{},"storage":{},"systemd":{"units":[{"contents":"[Service]\nType=oneshot\nExecStart=/usr/bin/echo Hello World\n\n[Install]\nWantedBy=multi-user.target","enabled":true,"name":"example.service"}]}}
```

How can i create a `systemd service` file using `terraform` and also what am i missing with above config, will this `ignition` work only with `centos`? Any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the error message, you could use [base64encode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/base64encode.html) function to apply Base64 encoding to a string.

```
 custom_data = base64encode(data.ignition_config.example.rendered)
```

I tried it with Azure VM image UbuntuServer 16.04-LTS
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, it looked like it worked, but it wont get stored in `/etc/systemd/system`? where can we find this file

Comment: "On Linux OS's, custom data is passed to the VM via the `ovf-env.xml` file, which is copied to the `/var/lib/waagent` directory during provisioning. Newer versions of the Microsoft Azure Linux Agent will also copy the base64-encoded data to `/var/lib/waagent/CustomData` as well for convenience." From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/custom-data#linux)